# Passing Down @Namespace using ForEach

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to pass down a namespace using ForEach, however I am getting an error that looks something like this.

**Multiple inserted views in matched geometry group Pair<String, ID>(first: "ID", second: SwiftUI.Namespace.ID(id: 73)) have `isSource: true`, results are undefined.**

I am not sure if its because I'm passing the namespace in the ForEach. The thing is that it works but I want to get rid of this error. I am also not sure if I'm passing the namespace correctly.

### MRE Code

```
struct DummyCard: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var title: String
}

let DummyCards: [DummyCard] = [
    DummyCard(title: "Dummy Card 1"),
    DummyCard(title: "Dummy Card 2"),
    DummyCard(title: "Dummy Card 3")
]

struct TestScreen2: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var selectedDummyID = ""
    @State var didClickBtn: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TabView(selection: $selectedDummyID) {
                        ForEach(DummyCards) { dummyCard in
                            DummyCardView(namespace: namespace, dummyCard: dummyCard, didClickBtn: $didClickBtn)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
                    .frame(height: 300)
                    .background(.green)
                    .padding(.top)
                    
                    Spacer()
                }
                .blur(radius: didClickBtn ? 8 : 0)
                .overlay(didClickBtn ? .red.opacity(0.3) : .clear)
                
                if didClickBtn {
                    Text("Make smalller")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "btn\(selectedDummyID)", in: namespace)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                                .fill(.black)
                                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "background\(selectedDummyID)", in: namespace)
                        )
                        .offset(y: 200)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                didClickBtn = false
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Hello")
            .onAppear {
                selectedDummyID = DummyCards.first?.id ?? ""
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DummyCardView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    var dummyCard: DummyCard
    @Binding var didClickBtn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(dummyCard.title)
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    didClickBtn = true
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Make bigger")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "btn\(dummyCard.id)", in: namespace)
                    .frame(width: 120, height: 44)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(.black)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "background\(dummyCard.id)", in: namespace)
                    )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Namespace is passed correctly. Make sure your views id are unique in all scenarios and matched only in one-to-one case.

Comment: @Asperi how would I be able to do that. I would think all the views already have UID and a one-to-one by passing down the dummy.id into the id of matchedGeometryEffect

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems no problem to work fine with trivial correction as shown at the code below on the  iOS15.4 Simulator of Xcode13.3.1 environment.
[code working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPxq9.png)
No error appears during opperating both TabView and Text backgrounded by RoundedRectangle.

```
+ .background(Color.green)
- .background(.green)
```